# Using multiple imputation on components of a derived variable

Tags: survival, multiple-imputation, clinical-trials

I have a time-to-event variable, where the occurrence of event is determined by 5 numerical components measured at pre-specified timepoints. Missing values are observed for some components at some timepoints. My question is, is it feasible to apply multiple imputation on the component scores in this instance?

For each imputation, a different choice of imputed values may also change whether an event has occurred for each subject, resulting in different event/censor distributions. Considering this, would Rubin's Rule still apply here to combine the KM/HR estimates for an overall result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a suitably applied multiple imputation can make a lot of sense in such a setting. In fact, it can often be a lot easier to impute more fine-grained scores as opposed imputing event times directly.

Similarly, with questionnaires where some questions may be unanswered at each timepoint, it is often a good idea to impute for each question first and then to calculate the overall score, while setting the overall score missing if not all questions are answered and imputing the overall score is a lot less efficient.

In the end, yes, you will get for each imputed dataset with imputed scores a corresponding dataset with imputed event indicators/times. Your intuition is right: you then analyze each of these imputed time-to-event datasets and combine the results using Rubin's rule. The main question here is: on what scale to combine (and whether we can get valid/useful standard errors on this scale). You want a scale where the normal assumptions in Rubin's rule are about right. So, e.g. the log-hazard ratio scale, if you are interested in hazard ratios (and similarly some transformed scale for survival curves).